# Equality constraint being ignored in MIP model

Tags: c++, linear-programming, gurobi, mixed-integer-programming

I have a MIP model ([Gurobi](http://www.gurobi.com)) which contains the following constraint:

```
model.addConstr(rawOutputVar == rawInputVar * edge->getMultiplicator());
```

`rawOutputVar` and `rawInputVar` are both continuous variables. `edge->getMultiplicator()` returns a small double.

Upon running the model I saw the the constraint was "ignored". The value of `rawInputVar` was set to 0, while `rawOutputVar` was a huge number, with `edge->getMultiplicator()` being `0.0000346`. So the equation became:

`100000000 == 0 * 0.0000346`

which is obviously wrong. Gurobi reported the solution as *optimal* however. I replaced the equation with

```
model.addConstr(rawOutputVar <= rawInputVar * edge->getMultiplicator());
model.addConstr(rawInputVar * edge->getMultiplicator() <= rawOutputVar);
```

which is basically the same. It now works correctly.

I am wondering why my first attempt did not work correctly. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

Comment: Did you have warning messages about numerical issues?

Comment: @GregGlockner I had the output disabled. I think it aborts automatically when numerical difficulties happen. See [here](http://gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman.pdf) on page 701: *NUMERIC: Optimization was terminated due to unrecoverable numerical difficulties.* My model reported *OPTIMAL* instead.